# How to use JSONP's callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have read up a lot on stackoverflow about everything on JSONP.

I am trying to get images from my web service but due to some domain policy, I have to use JSONP.

So currently here is my codes to get JSONP's data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/1?callback=test',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(test) {
        var content = ' ';
        for(var i=0; i<test.length;i++) {
            if(test.status == 0) {
                content += '<img src="' + result.images[i].s3File.url +'">';
            }
        }

        $( ".images" ).HTML(content);
    }
});
```

So what I am currently getting is..

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : http://example.com/1?callback=test?jQuery191014008507528342307_1414476410551&_=1414476410552:1
```

I read up a lot on this topic about the callback, but I really have no idea how do I use the callback function to retrieve the images. Can someone please teach me?

Comment: jQuery handles all the JSONP for you, but your server has to specifically support the JSONP format because the response from the server has to be entirely different for JSONP.  Does your server support JSONP responses (which are actually pieces of javascript)?  You shouldn't be putting the callback stuff in the URL yourself.  jQuery will manage that for you.

Comment: Try removing `test`. Just leave `callback=`.

Comment: i removed test. I am wondering if the server supports JSONP. I am going to ask the administrator

Comment: try callback=?, not callback=